# Trying to make buttons float right, but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have modified and installed this script (http://www.webcodo.net/grid-list-view-with-jquery-category-filter-cookie-support/#.Umiv7XCnpPE) on this page here -- http://www.helpmyedu.com/unitest.

What I'm trying to do is list four(4) buttons in each box floating to the right hand side.

For example -- i.imgur.com/BA7G2ti.jpg

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: place some html and css will help to answer.....

Comment: what have u tried please post ur effort inorder to help u..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a div enclosing the buttons which floats to right, instead of buttons floating to right by themselves.

Eg:

```
<div style="float:right">
  <div class="buy-ico" style="float:none"></div>
  <div class="buy-ico" style="float:none"></div>
</div>
```