# nav bar doesn't work anymore, after using float right

Tags: html, css

When I use `float: right` to move my nav bar to the right, the buttons won't work anymore; they just become text.

The layout is good but my nav bar just won't work anymore.
I tried margin and float but neither works.

I am new to this, so could someone help me?
Many thanks in advance.

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header
{
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),url(achtergrond.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-nav
{
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: right;         "-----> this command"
}
.main-nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a
{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.main-nav li.active a
{
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #272342;
}

.main-nav li:hover
{
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.logo img
{
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML as well?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557732/trying-to-make-buttons-float-right-but-it-doesnt-work.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but *you need to help yourself first*. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for he quick reply!
The HTML would be this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Business Website</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<header>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li><a href=""> HOME </a></li>
  <li><a href=""> SERVICES </a></li>
  <li><a href=""> ABOUT </a></li>
  <li><a href=""> CONTACT </a></li>
  <li><a href=""> NEWS </a></li>
  <li><a href=""> FAQ </a></li>
</ul>

    </div>

<div class="hero">
<h1> ASCO - engineered to preform </h1>

<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-one"> Watch Video</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-two"> Explore More </a>
</div>

</div>

</header>

</html>
```